# Swift to Swift 3 code conversions: Reading JSON files

Tags: json, swift, swift3, error-handling

I have this code for reading JSON files that I'm trying move into a Swift 3 environment. Here it is:

```
do {
    let dictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataOK, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as AnyObject!
        dictionaryOK = (dictionary as! NSDictionary as? Dictionary <String, AnyObject>)!
  }
catch {
    print("Level file '\(filename)' is not valid JSON: \(error)")
    return nil
}
```

Xcode gives suggestions to fix some errors (as some objects and classes have been renamed) which yields this:

```
do {
    //Problem here: parameters don't match overrides
    let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(dataOK as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as AnyObject!
    dictionaryOK = (dictionary as! NSDictionary as? Dictionary <String, AnyObject>)!
}
catch {
    print("Level file '\(filename)' is not valid JSON: \(error)")
    return nil
}
```

Which doesn't match any of the jsonObjects overrides (it says). I've checked the documentation which says the parameters for jsonObjects should be:

```
class func jsonObject(with data: Data, 
           options opt: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = []) throws -> AnyObject
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Swift 2 code is pretty verbose to begin with.

Try this:

```
do {
    if let dictionaryOK = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataOK, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] {
        // parse JSON
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```